# Is there a version of Pandas that will work with MicroPython?

Tags: pandas, micropython

I have a program that utilizes Pandas and Numpi which I want to operate on an ESP32 micro controller.  Is there a version of Pandas and Numpi that will work on the ESP32 so I can run the existing code program?

If yes, does anyone know of any tutorials or documentation I can reference to learn?  I know enough about Python and micro controllers to be dangerous. So please dumb it down .

Answer (score 3):

About Numpy, I think the most advance library is
[ulab](https://micropython-ulab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)